How to Add Multiple Conditions in WHEN Element in Azure DevOps Process XML?
I'm working on customizing a work item type in Azure DevOps and need to add multiple conditions within a WHEN element in the process XML. Specifically, I want to apply certain rules only when all specified conditions are met.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Make a field required when the work item is in the "Active" state.
Make the same field required when the work item type is "Bug".
Make the field read-only when it is assigned to a specific user.

One more case is

If State is Active and Custom.field value is 'a' then make field Custom.Abc readonly.

I've been able to define single conditions using the WHEN element, but I'm unsure how to combine multiple conditions for a single field. How can I structure the XML to include multiple WHEN conditions for a single field?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

What you need to know that the work item rules are defined in the XML file of each work item type (for example, Bug.xml) in a process. The rules defined in a work item type are only applied to current work item type and not to other work item types.
For example, in the Bug.xml file:

The field "Field01" is made as REQUIRED on the Bug type work item by default.
The field "Field02" will be made as REQUIRED when the first rule is met, made as READONLY when the second rule is met.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<witd:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0" xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef">
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" refname="Custom.Bug">
        <FIELDS>
            <FIELD name="Field01" refname="RefnameField01" type="xxxx">
                <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD name="Field02" refname="RefnameField02" type="xxxx">
                <WHEN ...>
                    <REQUIRED />
                </WHEN>
                <WHEN ...>
                    <READONLY />
                </WHEN>
            </FIELD>
            . . .
        </FIELDS>
        . . .
    </WORKITEMTYPE>
</witd:WITD>


EDIT:
Try to insert the <WHEN> element as the child of another <WHEN> element to combine the conditions as AND logical.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<witd:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0" xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef">
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" refname="Custom.Bug">
        <FIELDS>
            <FIELD name="Field02" refname="RefnameField02" type="xxxx">
                <WHEN ...>
                    <WHEN ...>
                        <REQUIRED />
                    </WHEN>
                </WHEN>
            </FIELD>
            . . .
        </FIELDS>
        . . .
    </WORKITEMTYPE>
</witd:WITD>



Hi @Bright Ran, Thank you for your answer. This will make required any one of the condition satisfies. How to check condition "Active" && "Bug" && "Specific User"  then make the field read only.

@SubrahmanyaBhat, Try to insert the <WHEN> element as the child of another <WHEN> element. See EDIT.

Looks like it is not allowed. Got error - The element 'WHEN' has invalid child element 'WHEN'. List of possible elements expected: 'REQUIRED, READONLY, EMPTY, FROZEN, CANNOTLOSEVALUE, NOTSAMEAS, VALIDUSER, ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE, MATCH, ALLOWEDVALUES, SUGGESTEDVALUES, PROHIBITEDVALUES, DEFAULT, COPY, SERVERDEFAULT'.

@SubrahmanyaBhat, I did not find other ways can do this.
